# Making sense of ($f$ being monic $\Leftrightarrow f_*$ injective) in non-locally small categories

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a locally small category. Then $f: c \to c'$ monic is equivalent to
$$
f_*: \text{Hom}(x,c) \to \text{Hom}(x,c'), \; (l: x \to c) \mapsto f \circ l
$$
being injectiv for all $x \in \mathscr{C}$.

**My question**: Is there a way to make sense of such an equivalence on categories which are not locally small? Might there be a way to speak of injective maps between classes?

*Background:* I always took this ($f$ being monic $\Leftrightarrow f_*$ injective) as the definition of a monomorphism since its seems to be both very intuitive and technically easy to work with. But I have only been able to do so since most categories I know are locally small.

Comment: What's wrong with defining injective functions between classes exactly as injective functions between sets?

Comment: @ArnaudD. I know nearly nothing about classes. I also know set theory (ZFC) only from an naive perspective, therefore I do not really understand the difference between a naive set and a proper class. I honestly have not imagined, till now, that it could be that easy. I hope that does not let my question look to stupid. I always knew maps as something defined between sets, so I assume to know nothing about morphisms between structures which are not even sets.

Comment: @Dominik For category-theoretic purposes, it is always sufficient to treat classes as simply a bigger kind of set. In fact the most popular foundation among category theory-minded mathematicians, that of Grothendieck universes, formalizes exactly this idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your category isn't locally small, then $f_*$ is in general not a function, but a functional. It is perfectly fine to define a functional $F$ to be injective iff it satisfies :
$$\forall a, b, \ F(a) = F(b) \Longrightarrow a = b $$
in other words, $f_*$ is injective iff
$$\forall a, b \in \operatorname{Hom}(x, c), \ f \circ a = f \circ b \Longrightarrow a = b $$
But that is the definition of $f$ being monic.